# How do I combine data of two tables and extend in it's row as array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, left-join, inner-join

I want to combine data of two tables and return it as `json`, but I can't seem to get it right. I've tried both with `INNER/LEFT` Join and with nested query's, but both without a valid result.

Here's how my tables are structured:

**events:**

```
----------------------------------
id |  title   | extra1 | extra2
----------------------------------
 1 | EventNo1 |  ...   |  ...
 2 | EventNo2 |  ...   |  ...
 3 | EventNo3 |  ...   |  ...
 4 | EventNo4 |  ...   |  ...
 5 | EventNo5 |  ...   |  ...
```

**images:**

```
----------------------------------
id | event | val | height | width
----------------------------------
 2 |   5   | xxx |  xxx   |  xxx
 3 |   2   | xxy |  xxx   |  xxx
 6 |   5   | xyx |  xxx   |  xxx
```

So basically what I want is to get the data from `events` and for each event where `images.event` matches `events.id` I want to extend with the data from `images`.

This is the json result I would like to achieve:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "EventNo1",
    "extra1": "...",
    "extra2": "...",
    "images": []
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "EventNo2",
    "extra1": "...",
    "extra2": "...",
    "images": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "val": "xxy",
        "height": "xxx",
        "width": "xxx"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "EventNo3",
    "extra1": "...",
    "extra2": "...",
    "images": []
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "title": "EventNo4",
    "images": []
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "title": "EventNo5",
    "extra1": "...",
    "extra2": "...",
    "images": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "val": "xxx",
        "height": "xxx",
        "width": "xxx"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "val": "xyx",
        "height": "xxx",
        "width": "xxx"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I accomplish this in php + mysqli?

Comment: Exactly. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've accepted "gaurav rai"'s. I tried his approach earlier, but where my objects were seperated. Didnt think of just extending them, which made me consider INNER/LEFT join's instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q = "select * from events";
$res = mysql_query($q);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
 $image_data= array();
 $q2 = "select * from images where event = ".$row['id'];
 $res2 = mysql_query($q2);
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
 $image_data[] = $row2;
 }
 $row['images'] = $image_data;
 $event_data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($event_data);
```

Comment: Damn, I was closer than I thought. I've already tried your approach, but where I had "images" in a seperate object. Didn't think of just extending it with "$row['images'] = $image_data;" Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-Code as I don't know what library/wrapper you use to access your database:

```php
$query = "select * from events";
$rows = $db->query($query);

foreach($rows as $k => $row) {
  $query = "select * from images where event = ".$row['id'];
  $rows[$k]['images'] = $db->query($query);
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

This is assuming that `$db->query()` returns the result set in form of an array, including an empty one if no rows where found.